Using \sisetup with siunitx package for automatic unit formatting
I am using LaTeX to write out homework for a Physics class. There are a lot of units in math notation that I need to write, so I am trying to make them as easy as possible. I used the {siunitx} package and I am trying to use \sisetup options to automatically parse and format units for numbers in equations:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  detect-all,          % Detect numbers and units in both math and text mode
  per-mode = symbol,     % Automatically handle units per operator like m/s
  output-decimal-marker = {.},  % For decimal points (optional)
  number-unit-product = \,,     % Adds a space between number and unit
  parse-numbers = true,   % Parse numbers automatically (use in math mode)    
}

\begin{document}
$$
\frac{235km}{2.85h} = 82.5km/h
$$
\end{document}

I added comments to help understand what the options of \sisetup are. The output of this code is this:

I want these numbers and units to be formatted as if they had \si{} (or qty{}{}) wrapped around them. Is this even possible to do with the {siunitx} package? I really don't want to have to write \si{} (or qty{}{}) for every single number.

unrelated, but have a look at Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

Instead of \si, you should be using \qty{...}{...} with the current siunitx

Thank you for the tips! I will change how I do equations going forward.

LaTeX is markup language and you must give instruction for any changes of ways how content in your document is presented. This meaning, that LaTeX should have instruction, when is writed quantities and when just ordinary equation. BTW, if you use new version (version 3) of siunitx, than you should complain to its syntax: only qty{...}{...} for quantities and \unit{...} for units. Mix of new and old (version 2) should not be mixed. And don't mix TeX syntax ($$) and LaTeX syntax for unnumbered equation. In LaTeX is correct \[  ... \]  or \begin{equation*} and \end{equation*}.

In my above comment instead of Mix of new and old (version 2) should not be mixed should be Mix of new  (version 3)  and old (version 2) siunitx syntax should not be used.

@Zarko So, are you saying that what I want is not possible? If so then I would love it if you could post an answer with some more detail! Thank you!

In spirit of siunitx package, your equation should be written as follows:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  per-mode = symbol,     % Automatically handle units per operator like m/s
         }

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\qty{235}{\kilo\metre}}{\qty{2.85}{\hour}} = \qty{82.5}{\kilo\metre\per\hour}
\]
\end{document}

which gives:

For a bit shorter writing you can instead \kilo\metre write just km. Use of longer units names is less error pronging (to my opinion), especial at more complex combination of units.
Writing expression with units on the way as you like to do has (a big) problem, how to distinguish when to numbers follows units or when follows some variables.

Alright, that works then. Thank you for your help! I'll just have to find a way to make writing \qty{}{} easier.
